# How to get info about previous versions of app in appstore?

Tags: javascript, api, app-store, itunes

I am trying to get all information about application in appstore, but response of `https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=${appId}` does not contain any info about previous versions and release notes, only about current version.

This info is available in desktop version of iTunes, but not on website, so I can't just parse HTML to get it.

How can I get this data?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm familiar with the API documentation over at [Apple](https://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api/), you're not able to retrieve update information via the API.

I recommend a service like AppAnnie, which is for free if you link your developer account with it. (Basically you share your data with them) There you'll get the data you want. See the example below:

[image]